# how do I control where text is printed to console via fmt?

Tags: go

When running vim if I type `:` the input cursor goes to bottom row of the screen and I can type a command, then go back to the top of the screen. Arrow keys let me move around, all that jazz. In Golang using the fmt package how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're kind of confused. What `fmt` is essentially equivalent to are C's `printf` and `scanf` family of functions. The complexity of controlling the screen buffer is quite a bit more complex than just printing some stuff in a terminal output.

The behavior you're talking about is a result of vim's integration with the [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library (or something similar to it). Haven't ever used this, but [here](https://github.com/rthornton128/goncurses)'s a link to an ncurses wrapper in cgo, which you could probably use to do something like vim does.

Comment: perfect! yes, thank u, my question was not asked very well. ncurses is just what I'm looking for.